# match http|https with fasteRoute in Slim3

Tags: php, slim-3, fastroute

here my sample [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) for slim3 :

```
$app->get('/api/search/[{domaine}[/{notused:.+}]]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index.phtml', $args);
});
```

with this FastRoute "regex" ([{domaine}[/{notused:.+}]]), I match :

```
/api/search/sample.com  
/api/search/sample.com/test  
/api/search/
```

And $args['domaine'] return "sample.com".

but I want to match this too :

```
/api/search/http://sample.com  
/api/search/https://sample.com
```

add new route like this work :

```
$app->get('/api/search/http://[{domaine}[/{notused:.+}]]' ...   
$app->get('/api/search/https://[{domaine}[/{notused:.+}]]' ...
```

But it's better to have just one line.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better when you use an url encoded url as query parameter.

But when you really what to use this, you could regex the http(s) part as well

```
$app->get('/api/search/{urlSchema:https?}://[{domaine}[/{notused:.+}]]', ..);
```

that means it requires `http` and then have 0-1 `s`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For me it does not work. But I retain the solition